# volatile for signal handler and multi-threading

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, volatile

It is said volatile is needed for signal handler, e.g.,

```
volatile int flag = 1; // volatile is needed here?

void run() {
    while(flag) { /* do someting... */ }
}

void signal_handler(int sig) {
    flag = 0;
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
    run();
    // ...
}
```

It is said volatile is often not used in multithreading. But how about the similar case like above in multithreading:

```
int flag = 1; // is volatile needed here?

void thread_function() {
    while(flag) { /* do someting... */ }
}

int main() {
    // pthread_create() to create thread_function()...
    sleep(10); // let thread_function run for 10 seconds
    flag = 0;
    // ...
}
```

Should the volatile keyword be used in both cases? Are the two cases treated the same way by compiler?

Comment: `volatile` is [usually] insufficient for interthread operations (e.g. locking, ring queue indexes, etc). But, your usage here is for a "run" flag. Only 1 writer (`main`). And, in both cases, it should be `volatile`. In the second case, assume the thread func is `while (flag) do_stuff();`, `main` clearing `flag` is a "gentle" way to tell threads to exit their loops, do cleanup, and exit. You could combine 1st and 2nd and have the signal handler clear `flag` for the threads. Much beyond this for threads needs `pthread_mutex_t` et. al., etc.

Comment: I would use a `std::atomic_flag` (which is always lock-free on every system) or a `std::atomic_signal_fence`. `volatile` only forces the compiler to read and write from the specified memory location instead of optimizing the value out. The memory location could also just be the cache. volatile` does not prevent the compiler from reordering your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`volatile` is used to make sure that the contents of the variable is read from its actual location (memory, in our case) rather than from a CPU register.

In other words, whenever an "outside" event might change the value of a variable, you should consider using `volatile` ("outside" - as in, outside the relevant code block).

In both your examples, you are using the variable as a flag to signal a change in behavior. This flag, in both examples, is controlled by events "outside" the loop that that is reviewing the flag. For this reason, both examples require the use of the `volatile` keyword.

It should be noted `volatile` does **not** provide thread safety for a number of reasons. To make sure an object is thread safe, read/write operations must be either protected or atomic.

Comment: ...and when read/write operations are protected or atomic, you no longer need `volatile`

Comment: @M.M - Although that's true it's still good practice to use volatile with protected operations. Although C11 atomic variables are always read from memory rather than CPU (when using `atomic_load`), variables that are changed within a lock are "implied" to be volatile... but optimizations can do funny things when the data is read outside of the lock, such as in the OPs examples.

Comment: C's `volatile` has nothing to do with memory. You're thinking of Java. C's `volatile` prohibits the compiler from optimizing away any accesses and also prohibits reordering with respect to other operations that have visible side effects.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas there's [an explanation here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/volatile), but in general, the rules of the abstract machine require memory read/write to the volatile object. From the standard: "_An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways **unknown to the implementation** or have other unknown side effects. Therefore any expression referring to such an object **shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine**_" ... so I think it answers the question about flags in multi-threading code.

Comment: @Myst Nothing in either the linked-to page nor in what you wrote specifically says that all volatile accesses **_must_** read from or write to main memory.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas - I did not say **main** memory. `volatile` is **not** atomic (though on some systems with some aligned types it is atomic by hardware design). However, performing a "load" (`MOV`) from the location of the variable (memory, in this case) is **required** by the rules of the abstract machine for **each time a `volatile` value is accessed**, since the compiler cannot assume that the memory wasn't mutated or affected by a previous `MOV` (even reading might mutate the value).

Comment: @Myst Yes, I know `volatile` is not guaranteed atomic. The machine has no idea a variable was declared `volatile` in the source C program. For MMIO, yes, the _machine_ loads the value from memory every time, but this has _nothing_ to do with it being declared `volatile`. `volatile` in C _only_ prohibits the _compiler_ (and _only_ the compiler) from performing its _own_ optimizations independent of whatever the machine does. Hence, `volatile` has _nothing_ to do with _any_ memory (main or any cache).

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas , it effects the resulting machine code. The CPU can’t optimize a memory read instruction away and read a CPU register instead. The variable is always accessed from it’s actual location and never cached (except by L-level CPU caching). I really don’t understand what you believe to be unclear about the answer, but this discussion is obviously beyond the scope of both the question and the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221581/discussion-between-paul-j-lucas-and-myst).

Answer (score 12):

The only non-local values you are allowed to modify from a signal handler are those of type `volatile sig_atomic_t`, and atomic types. In particular, writing to your `volatile int` is *not* allowed, and if your signal handler runs you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Useful, if slightly tangential, addition: while you are not allowed very much in the context of a signal handler, you can `write()` to a file descriptor. That's often the most useful way to get word of the 'event' out to your main program logic. Linux even offers a convenient [`signalfd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) API for precisely that usage pattern (i.e. instead of writing your signal handlers which explicitly forward the event, register a `signalfd` to read the events from).

Comment: Are you allowed to modify atomic types other than `sig_atomic_t`? I thought it was the only one; otherwise, why would it be necessary at all?

Comment: Atomic types have to be lock-free for signal handlers, but which they usually are if the base type is a standard integer type.

Comment: @rici, other than the name indicates `sig_atomic_t` is not an atomic type, unfortunately. It predates C11 and the introduction of threads and atomics and *must* be provided by all C platforms, whereas threads and atomics are optional.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Never mind, I found the reference in the C standard. There's an exception for "lock-free atomic objects" which doesn't appear in Posix.

Comment: @user268396 you mean to change the first case like this: "volatile sig_atomic_t flag = 1;"? The question is if volatile is still needed in signal handler case, how about in the multithreading one?

Comment: GNU says: "In practice, you can assume that int is atomic. You can also assume that pointer types are atomic; that is very convenient. Both of these assumptions are true on all of the machines that the GNU C Library supports and on all POSIX systems we know of." https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Atomic-Types.html I think this means that it's OK to read/write a `volatile int` or `volatile char*` in a signal handler on such a system. (But according to the spec, it's still undefined behavior, and it may lead to problems on other systems.)

Answer (score 4):

The c++ standard, in [intro.execution], paragraph 6, tells:

> When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by receipt of a signal, the values of objects which are neither
>            — of type volatile std::sig_atomic_t nor
>            — lock-free atomic objects (29.4)
>   are unspecified during the execution of the signal handler, and the value of any object not in either of these two categories that is modified by the handler becomes undefined.

Therefore, yes, for signal handlers, you have to use `volatile std::sig_atomic_t`.